# What is the name of this moth found in Virginia USA?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found in Virginia, USA on Nov 1 2015, 10:34 AM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, found it. It is called a Euonymus Leaf Notcher Moth. It is an invasive species from Asia. It was first found in Maryland and Virginia in 2001.

http://www.insectid.ento.vt.edu/exotic-pests/euonymus/